# Домены приложений и безопасность

Tags: c#, .net

В доменах приложений есть такая штука, как политики, которые позволяют ограничить домен в правах.

Например, запретить доступ к файловой системе.

Однако, работает ли это на практике?

Разве, когда делается Unwarp, то сборка из домена не загружается в основной домен?

=> если сборка вредоносная, то можно запихать в статический конструктор какую-то гадость, например format c => безопасность рушится, даже если домен был ограничен в правах.

Или не все так просто, или с доменами работают по другому?

Comment: *Разве, когда делается Unwarp, то сборка из домена не загружается в основной домен?* А зачем Вы делаете `Unwrap`? Через границу доменов приложения не следует передавать объекты, определённые в частично доверенных сборках. По хорошему, частично доверенные сборки должны находиться по отдельному пути, который не включён в список путей для поиска сборок для основного домена.

Comment: @PetSerAl не знаю ситуации автора, но могу привести пример: ты пишешь приложение и систему плагинов для него; плагины не доверенные, должны реализовать определенный интерфейс. Например методы `bool CanProcess(object)` и `void Process(object)`. Ты хочешь загрузить этот плагин в отдельный AppDomain с ограничениями, и вызывать эти методы, уверенный, что это не повлечёт неожиданного удаления данных с файловой системы. Вероятно, имеет место неправильное проектирование системы.

Comment: @LunarWhisper Если честно, то я совершенно не понял, как Ваш комментарий соотносится с моим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, Unwrap загрузит сборку и в основной домен тоже. Поэтому правильно делается по-другому:

1. создается в основной, доверенной, сборке класс-наследник MarshalByRefObject;
2. экземпляр этого класса загружается в новом домене, и *ему* (доверенному экземпляру) делается Unwrap;
3. все дальнейшее взаимодействие с объектами в новом домене делается через этот объект.

---

Для ситуации плагинов имеет смысл для каждого интерфейса, который может быть плагином реализован, подготовить свой кросс-доменный прокси для загрузки в домене плагина. В простейшем случае такой прокси будет просто делегировать все вызовы:

```
class FooCrossDomainProxy: MarshalByRefObject, IFoo
{
    private readonly IFoo target;

    public void FooCrossDomainProxy(IFoo target) 
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void Bar() => target.Bar();
}
```

В более сложном случае этому прокси можно поручить адаптацию интерфейса к кросс-доменному взаимодействию. К примеру, поскольку вызовы между доменами медленные - имеет смысл снижать их число путем объединения методов:

```
class FooCrossDomainProxy: MarshalByRefObject
{
    private readonly IFoo target;

    public void FooCrossDomainProxy(IFoo target) 
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public bool TryBar() 
    {
        if (!target.CanBar)
            return false;

        target.Bar();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: В комментариях привели пример с плагинами. Получается, что для плагинов нужно ставить ограничение- обязательное наследование от MarshaByRefObject?

Comment: Нет. Это **вы** должны реализовать кросс-доменный прокси для всех **своих** интерфейсов расширения.